# How would I invoke a rake script inside my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I want to execute a rake script from within a model.  Beside calling it via backtick, is there anyway to include the rake library and call Rake::Task['some_task'].invoke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but if it's shared code why not make it a module? You'd avoid duplication and be able to use it wherever you need to.

Answer (score 2):

you can use 'system' to run it, but I agree with Andy, it should be shared to avoid duplication